# iPhone connection to localhost rails sarver

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, iphone, xcode

I am creating Rails server for iPhone app.
I want to debug on iPhone device not on iPhone simulator.
So, I connect iPhone to mac book air by USB, and connect to Rails server.
But, iPhone could not connect to Rails server.

Environment
Rails 4.2.3
Server localhost:3000
Xcode 6.4 
iPhone iOS 8.4.1 
en0 inet 192.168.11.7

As long As I searched, when iPhone device connect to localhost server, the url is http://192.168.11.7:3000/~.
But, mac console show nothing and xcode show "The request timed out." after a while.

If anyone know how to fix the problem, please tell me.

Comment: It might also help if you bind your rails server's IP to `0.0.0.0` with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I already use -b 0.0.0.0 option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the wonderful http://xip.io/

You don't need to install anything - just go to

```
http://192.168.11.7.xip.io:3000
```

on your phone.

If you want to use a particular domain name, eg if your app behaves differently depending on domain names or subdomains, you can do eg

```
http://mydomain.foo.192.168.11.7.xip.io:3000
```

EDIT:  my answer is actually about connecting to your server over the internet rather than a usb cable.  I'd recommend that you use the internet rather than the USB option if possible as it's simpler.  xip.io will not work if you can't access the internet.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried "http://192.168.11.7.xip.io:3000", but the result is same before. The console shows nothing. Could you have any ideas about this problem?

Comment: When you say "the console" do you mean the log output from your server?  Can you connect to the internet ok, eg a regular website, on the device?
Try going to that same url in a web browser on your computer.

Comment: The console is log output from server. Device can connect to the internet and can access website. I tried to connect the url in the web browser by my device & my mac. But, my server's console shows nothing. The browser shows 'error connection refused'.

Comment: Maybe that's not the right ip address.  You should be able to get to the ip on your local computer without the xip.io part, eg "http://192.168.11.7:3000".  Check the network address of the computer that's hosting rails.  is it definitely `192.168.11.7` ?

Comment: I tried to connect to "192.168.11.7:3000" in mac web browser, and The browser could connect to it, and Rail server console shows the details. But, from iPhone web browser could not connect to "192.168.11.7:3000" & "192.168.11.7.xip.io:3000". The console shows nothing.

Comment: Does `http://192.168.11.7.xip.io:3000` work in your web browser on your computer?  On my iphone i am able to connect to my rails app via `http://192.168.18.25.xip.io:3000/`, where 192.168.18.25 is my local network IP.  Is your phone connected via wifi to the same network that your computer is on?

Comment: I checked the wifi and noticed that iPhone and mac connected to different wifi. By using same wifi, iPhone can connect to Rails server. Thank you for your comment. If your comment nothing, I could not solve this problem.

Comment: glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried that but funny enough, in my case **turning my iPhone off and on again actually fixed the issue**.

I had the same problem, my app was working fine and all of a sudden it stopped working although nothing had changed. I could access the internet, the browser was accessing the rails app url just fine but my iOS app did not seem to be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run my iOS app from Xcode with my local rails server to my device and xip.io was the solution.

Get the ip address of your computer from the wireless network you are connected to and put that into networking.swift like so.

```
http://11.1.11.100.xip.io:3000
```

Make sure the rails server is running and your device is connected to the same network as your computer and build the app.